# Minimum of Two Maybes

Tags: haskell, option-type

I want to get the minimum of two maybe values, or if one is nothing get the non-nothing one, or return nothing if both inputs are nothing. I can write a simple function to do this, but I suspect there is a way to do this without writing a custom function. Sorry, if this is a petty question, but is there a simpler way than using this custom function?

```
minMaybe :: Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
minMaybe Nothing b = b
minMaybe a Nothing = a
minMaybe (Just a) (Just b) = Just $ min a b
```

Comment: before I get downvoted by that pigworker ;) ... what about: `let minM a b = maybe a Just $ maybe b Just $ min a b
` ?

Comment: Maybe [just this](http://ideone.com/GH4K7K)

Comment: n.m, that works, but it's not any simpler that what I'm starting with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the `Applicative`, or `Monad` instance for this, since any `Nothing` in those contexts will have your total result being a `Nothing`. That being said, the term *"simpler"* is highly opinionated, and your function is fine as it is.

Comment: Note: Community wiki since "simpler" is highly opinionated.

Comment: Since `max` works as @clay would want it to ("preferring" Just values to Nothings), perhaps if @clay used Data.Ord.Down then they would have the behaviour they want, while still being 'simpler' in the way the other answers want it to.

Answer (score 22):

It is possible to satisfy the specification using operators from `Control.Applicative`.

```
myMin :: Ord x => Maybe x -> Maybe x -> Maybe x
myMin a b = min <$> a <*> b <|> a <|> b
```

where the `<|>` for `Maybe` implements "preference"

```
Nothing <|> b  = b
a       <|> _  = a
```

The thing is

```
min <$> Just a <*> Just b = Just (min a b)
```

but

```
min <$> Just a <*> Nothing = Nothing
```

which has resulted in some incorrect answers to this question. Using `<|>` allows you to prefer the computed `min` value when it's available, but recover with either individual when only one is `Just`.

**But** you should ask if it is appropriate to use `Maybe` in this way. With the inglorious exception of its `Monoid` instance, `Maybe` is set up to model failure-prone computations. What you have here is the extension of an existing `Ord` with a "top" element.

```
data Topped x = Val x | Top deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

and you'll find that `min` for `Topped x` is just what you need. It's good to think of types as not just the representation of data but the equipment of data with structure. `Nothing` usually represents some kind of failure, so it might be better to use a different type for your purpose.

Comment: `Topped x` has a sensible `max`, but if you want to add a *bottom* element instead, then the intended semantics changes, so why should the type stay the same? Of course, we could do the "make a monoid from a semigroup" construction once, then wrap `max`, `min`, etc as semigroup structures.

Comment: `min <$> a <*> b == min a b` on `Maybe`s. The latter however does look more "golfed" than "simpler"...

Comment: @chi Huh, that means that if the question had used `max` instead of `min`, `max` would have been a correct answer. Or put differently, `Bottomed` is just `Maybe` itself.

Comment: I know I'm quite late to this question, but what the heck. The monoid-extras package on Hackage offers [this type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras-0.4.2/docs/Data-Monoid-Inf.html) (and the `Bottomed` variant, too) and a few small utilities for working with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can write it using the `Alternative` instance of `Maybe`:

```
minMaybe a b = liftA2 min a b <|> a <|> b
```

Alternatively, you could use `maxBound` as default, so it'll always choose the other:

```
minMaybe a b = liftA2 min (d a) (d b)
  where d x = x <|> Just maxBound
```

But I don't recommend that.

Answer (score 2):

Question is about lifting function `min :: Ord a ⇒ a → a → a` to work with `Maybe`s context. It's associative so `Semigroup` instance does exactly what you want:

```
min' :: forall a. Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
min' = coerce ((<>) @(Maybe (Min a)))
```

This requires `ScopedTypeVariables` and `TypeApplications`. `coerce` comes from `Data.Coerce`. More old fashioned solution given below. But version above should be more performant: `coerce` doesn't exist at runtime. Although GHC may eliminate `fmap`s there's no guarantee:

```
min'' :: Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
min'' x y = fmap getMin (fmap Min x <> fmap Min y)
```

P.S. I would say that your solution is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think radomaj had a [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769820/minimum-of-two-maybes#comment40362735_25770054).

```
import Data.Ord (Down (..))
import Data.Function (on)

minMaybes mx my =
  getDown <$> (max `on` fmap Down) mx my
getDown (Down x) = x
```

We use `max` to prefer `Just` to `Nothing`, and then use `Down` so we actually get the minimum if both are `Just`.

---

Here's another, similar approach that seems a bit cleaner. `Maybe` can be seen a way to tack on an extra minimal value, `Nothing`, to an arbitrary `Ord` type. We can write our own type to tack on a maximal value:

```
data AddMax a = TheMax | Plain a deriving Eq
instance Ord a => Ord (AddMax a) where
  TheMax <= Plain _ = False
  _ <= TheMax = True
  Plain a <= Plain b = a <= b

maybeToAddMax :: Maybe a -> AddMax a
maybeToAddMax = maybe TheMax Plain

addMaxToMaybe :: AddMax a -> Maybe a
addMaxToMaybe TheMax = Nothing
addMaxToMaybe (Plain a) = Just a
```

Now you can write

```
minMaybes mx my = addMaxToMaybe $
  (min `on` maybeToAddMax) mx my
```

You can also pull a little sleight-of-hand:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}
import Data.Ord
import Data.Function
import Data.Coerce

newtype AddMax a = AddMax {unAddMax :: Down (Maybe (Down a))}
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

Now

```
minMaybes :: forall a. Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
minMaybes = coerce (min @(AddMax a))
```

Comment: this breaks the separation of concerns principle -- involves the outer structure in comparisons of carried data (or IOW, can't be changed into `maxMaybes` by just using `min`). `Down` also flips the choice for equals.....

Comment: @WillNess, you can fix the choice for equals by doubling down: wrap it around the outside as well as the inside. I agree it's lousy for separation of concerns.

Comment: I tried double-Down, could't make it work...  what I have: `data X a = X (a,a)` that compares pairs by first element only; then `max [Down $ X (1,2)] [Down $ X (1,3)]` returns `[Down (X (1,3))]`. Using `Down` twice doesn't change this (as `max (Down [Down $ X (1,2)]) (Down [Down $ X (1,3)])`). How should this be done?

Comment: @WillNess, with double-down, you use `min`.

Comment: thanks. for some reason, `max (X (1,2)) (X (1,3))` returns `X (1,3)`, that's what threw me off. the whole distinguishable equals thing doesn't go quite well with purity anyway.